# Batch chinese(?) symbols change in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, bluetooth, chinese-locale

Related to this problem: [Error code 259 when trying to pair using Bluetooth Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800133/error-code-259-when-trying-to-pair-using-bluetooth-command-line-tools)

I made a simple batch that pairs my bluetooth gamepad with my PC, but unfortunately the gamepads screen name is in chinese(?) and when I run the batch the symbols are different in the cmd than in the batch.

I'm using [Bluetooth Command Line Tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/)

Here's the batch:

```
rem @echo off
btpair -p -n"小米蓝牙手柄"
if errorlevel 1 goto error
exit

:error
pause
exit
```

...and here's what it looks like in the cmd window:

```
C:\Windows\system32>rem @echo off

C:\Windows\system32>btpair -p -n"Õ░Åþ▒│ÞôØþëÖµëïµƒä"
Remote device "ıª┼■ªªÌ¶Ï■ÙÍÁÙ´Áâõ" not found.

C:\Windows\system32>if errorlevel 1 goto error

C:\Windows\system32>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I tested it manually (copy-pasted the name to cmd) and it worked, but not from batch.

As you can see I have a problem here...
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the command line tool `devcon.exe` from Microsoft to disable and re-enable just that piece of hardware - it should re-pair the device as a side effect I am guessing.

Changing the codepage with the `chcp` command in the batch file may help with the chinese characters.

Comment: Thanks, but I already gave up. I've had some much trouble with the controller anyways, what with having to emulate a xbox360 controller to get it to work in most games and all the problems with making the connection. I'll much rather use my usb xbox360 controller.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your system locale to have chinese character input/output.
*Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative -> Change system locale... -> Current system locale (change it here)*

Comment: And there is no way to have the batch transfer the characters to cmd other than changing the locale? Either way I already gave up. The controller has so much trouble connecting to my PC in any case that it's just not worth it...

Comment: No, since English or other locales don't have chinese character, so changing locale should help you